# New Employee workflow

Tags: open-source, json, workflow

I would like to prototype a workflow for New Employees.

I have a REST web service which resturns a JSON containing all new employees and their information (name, position, dept, email, manager email, etc.).

The requirements of the workflow are not fully specified yet, however at a minimum, I would like to be able to:

- Notify the employees manager
- Allow the manager to check certain items for procurement
- Trigger notifications to relevant teams, depending on which items the manager has selected.

The system should be able to integrate with Active Directory. The OS may be Windows or Linux.

I am leaning towards Open Source options, however something scalable is preferable if we need to pay for Enterprise software.